# Getting text between ** in Java

Tags: java, string

Thanks everyone!

So my instructions are:

**Method name:** emphasize

**Parameter:** a Scanner object containing words

**Return value:** a String where anything between a pair of asterisks is all uppercase

**Example:** `emphasize(new Scanner("I am so *happy* right now! "))` should return `I am so HAPPY right now!`

**Notes:** Your method should work even if the `Scanner` object contains no words.

The asterisks will only come in pairs. There will never be an odd number of asterisks.

I figured the first step would be to return the value between `* *` as caps.

```
public static String emphasize(Scanner bold)
{
    String str = bold.nextLine();
    String answer = str.substring(str.indexOf("(") + 1, str.indexOf("*"));
    String caps = "";

    return answer.toUpperCase();    
}
```

is what I have so far, but Java doesnt like it when I use two `* *` to find the item, it give me all sorts of error. I can do one * and a ) but not two, any ideas?

Comment: I "think" you're suppose to use `Scanner#next` to check each word, then you should be able to use `String#startsWith` and `String#endsWith` to find the `*`characters. You could then use a `StringBuilder` to build the result based on your other needs

Comment: thanks madprogrammer! Ill check the api for those methods!

Comment: You can use Stack, push star and while stack has item uppercase the letter and when you see other star operator pop stack item and your stack will be empty.

Comment: use lastIndexOf to get the last *.

Comment: Hi @Elchapo, You regex to match all string need to be changed. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `regex` It will match all the character that need to be changed into uppercase

```
public static void main(String args[]){  
  System.out.println(emphasize(new Scanner("hello *Stack*overflow *again*")));    
}

public static String emphasize(Scanner bold) {
    String input = bold.nextLine();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\*)(.*?)(\\*)");

    Matcher m  = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        String matchedString = m.group().toString();
         input = input.replace(matchedString, matchedString.substring(1, matchedString.length()-1).toUpperCase());
     }
    return input;
}
```

o/p : `hello STACKoverflow AGAIN`

I would suggest you to use `Regex` match

Comment: use bold.hasNext() for the case -  if the Scanner object contains no words.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this, but I was told not to use an array, also I was told to use a scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static Pattern EMP_PAT = Pattern.compile("\\*([^*]*)\\*|([^*]*)");

public static String emphasize(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher m = EMP_PAT.matcher(s);
    while (m.find())
        sb.append(m.group(1) != null ? m.group(1).toUpperCase() : m.group(2));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works I think. But code is a bit ugly.

```
public static String emphasize(Scanner bold) {
    String emphasizedSentence = "";
    while (bold.hasNext()) {
        String str = bold.nextLine();
        if (str.contains("*")) {
            String[] splitted = str.split("\\*");
            for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    str = str.replace("*" + splitted[i] + "*", splitted[i].toUpperCase());
                }
            }
            emphasizedSentence = str;

        }

    }
    return emphasizedSentence;
}
```

input:

```
System.out.println(emphasize(new Scanner("hello *Stack*overflow")));
```

output:

```
hello STACKoverflow
```

**Another input :** `System.out.println(emphasize(new Scanner("hello *Stack*overflow *again*")))`

Comment: What if my input has two words to be changed to uppercase

Comment: The asterisks will only come in pairs. There will never be an odd number of asterisks.(or Empty) - from the question. or use str.contains("*")

Comment: I have added new inpu tin Another input. Will it give the correct answer ?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of way doing this.

```
public static String emphasize(Scanner bold) {
    String str = "";
    while(bold.hasNext()) {
        String word = bold.next();
        if (word.indexOf("*") != -1 && word.lastIndexOf("*") != -1) {
            String answer = word.substring(word.indexOf("*")+1, word.lastIndexOf("*"));
            str += " " + answer.toUpperCase() + " ";
        } else {
            str += " " + word + " ";
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

So `emphasize` method can make all words between ** uppercase. You can also do the same with a regex.

Comment: what do the -1 do here?if (word.indexOf("*") != -1 && word.lastIndexOf("*") != -1) { and the +1 on the next line?

Comment: This is to make sure that we're actioning on the word we're looking for. In this case `word.indexOf("*")` checks to see if we have found a word that starts with `*` and the second part `word.lastIndexOf("*")` checks if we have found any ending `*` for the same word. Because there can be words such as `*angry` where there is no ending `*`. So we have to make sure we're dealing with the right word.

Comment: `+1` is because `indexof` index is 0 based and we don't want to make `*` uppercase; only the word is needed to be in uppercase.

Comment: I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
 at assign3.LoopPatterns.emphasize(LoopPatterns.java:88)
 at assign3.LoopPatterns.main(LoopPatterns.java:108)
when I run that? any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `emphasize ` I posted. I tested it and seems to work correctly. Can I see the sentence you're testing against? Are you doing some other processing before calling the `emphasize ` method ? I just want to see the string value passed to `emphasize ` method.

Comment: Ahh my mistake its working, so to review: this is how it works: while the scanner has input left. the string word is = to the next token

if the token begins with * and ends with * (here I am confuse as to why there is a negative -1) than the string answer = the same string, but we added a substring method clarifying that everything between * and * is to be bolded/

is that correct?

why do you need str += "" + ___ + "";?

Comment: Yes, you're right. substring method is to get the actual to-be-bolded word from `*word*` token. And -1 check is to see if we have found the right word. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String) how to use `indexOf` method.  `str += "" + ___ + "";` is to reconstruct the sentence since we have modified one or more words by bolding them.

Answer (score 0):

you can matching *word* with regex, in java you can use :

```
String text = "I am so *happy* right now!";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\*+[A-Z]+\\*\\B").matcher(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        String line=input.nextLine();
        String output=Stream.of(line.split(" ")).flatMap(new Function<String, Stream<String>>() {

            @Override
            public Stream<String> apply(String s) {
            if(s.startsWith("*") && s.endsWith("*")) {
                return Stream.of(s.replace("*","").trim().toUpperCase());
            }
            return Stream.of(s);
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        System.out.println(output);

}
```

**Output**

I am so *angry* on *her*

I am so ANGRY on HER